# Is a graph a contraction of itself?

Tags: graph-theory

That is, is the identity map from a simple graph G to itself a contraction or do you have to contract vertices (or an edge)? If so, does this mean G is a minor of itself?

Comment: it's not a proper minor.

Comment: In most contexts, any graph is defined to be a minor of itself. For example, Wagner's Theorem (Kuratowski for minors) states that a graph is planar if and only if it has no $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ minor. But $K_5$ itself is non-planar, so this only makes sense if $K_5$ is a minor of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Jon's comment is right on track.  A minor of a graph is the result of contracting edges (possibly none), while a proper minor is the result of contracting one or more edges.

To answer your question outright, G is a minor of itself, but it is not a proper minor of itself.  Sometimes we care if a graph is a proper minor, sometimes it needs to just be a minor (as in the case of Kuratowski's theorem as Perry has pointed out in comment.